# How to list all contacts with Microsoft Graph?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am experimenting with the Microsoft Graph API and I set up a project with the QuickStarts on the Microsoft developers site.

I'm currently having problems when trying to list all email contacts associated with the logged account.

My problem seems to reside on how I'm requesting and passing the information to `ViewBag` as it throws a `NullReference` exceptions even with the proper front-end listing.

Here is the relevant code:

HomeController.cs

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> GetMyContacts()
{
    try
    {
        // Init GraphServiceClient
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = SDKHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient();
        var contacts = await graphService.GetMyEmailContacts(graphClient);
        ViewBag.Contacts = contacts;

        return View("Graph");
    }
    catch (ServiceException se)
    {
        if (se.Error.Message == Resource.Error_AuthChallengeNeeded) return new EmptyResult();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error", new { message = Resource.Error_Message + Request.RawUrl + ": " + se.Error.Message });
    }
}
```

GraphService.cs

```cs
public async Task<IList<Contact>> GetMyEmailContacts(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
{
    User me = await graphClient.Me.Request().Select("mail,userPrincipalName").GetAsync();
    var contacts = me.Contacts;
    return contacts;
}
```

Graph.cshtml

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
<pre name="user-contacts">@ViewBag.Contacts</pre>
</div>
<h2>TEST GET CONTACTS</h2>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<p>@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Contacts)</p>
</div>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you please show your forontend code for Graph view ?

Comment: @KrzysztofLa Done

Answer (score 2):

In your view, you have to cast it back to the original type. ViewBag is a C# 4 dynamic type. Returned entities are also dynamic unless cast.

```
var contactList = ViewBag.Contacts as IEnumerable<Contact>;
```

If you want to display the whole list, it's as simple as this:

```
@foreach (var contact in contactList)
{
    <li>@contact</li>
}
```

Comment: I get that but my problem seems to reside on how I'm requesting and passing the information to ViewBag as it throws a NullReference exceptions even with the proper front-end listing @KrzysztofLa

Comment: You should mention than on your question... Btw. You will get a null exception if you do not pass any model to the view and still have the view bound to a model. Make sure that you are passing this model from controller to view. `@model YourModel`